# SOLR search index not updating

Tags: solr, indexing

I've renamed fields on a Sitecore template from uuid to uuid2, but for some records the solr index contains items with the field name uuid (in SOLR admin).

I've populated my SOLR schemas again and rebuilt the index, but still some (but not all) records are using the old field name. I've also tried deleting the Sitecore data that is indexed and re-added it, but I still have the same issue.

What am I missing and how can I fix it?

Comment: does the record which contain the old field name has the attribute `_latestversion` set to true or false?

Comment: Did you reload the index after updating the schema?

Comment: @adarsh Use _latestversion is true

Comment: @AdamSeabridge - I rebuilt the index through the Indexing Manager. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Won’t hurt to run a database cleanup task from control panel. Could be orphaned items not receiving the field update yet _are_ being indexed.

Comment: @jrap Thanks but the db cleanup didnt help